# How to apply specific formatting to a label in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make the email label bold in my _email.html.erb view. For doing this I mentioned this in my _email.html.erb:

```
<tr>
  <td><label for="user_email" class="label_account_request">E-mail address: </label></td>
  <td><%= text_field 'user', 'email', class: "form-control width-250"  %></td>
</tr>
```

My application using some custom formats like this:

```
@import "font-awesome";
@import "jquery.ui.all";
@import "jquery.datetimepicker";
@import "ajaxtabs";
@import "balloontip";
@import "colorbox";
@import "dddropdownpanel";
@import "flash_messages";
@import "grades";
@import "goldberg";
@import "layout_2";
@import "redbox";
@import "react-simpletabs/dist/react-simpletabs";
@import "jquery.datetimepicker";
$icon-font-path: "bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "navbar";
@import "tree_display";
@import "awesomplete";
@import "user_pastebins";
@import "login_form";
@import "three_state_toogle";
@import "table_sorter";
@import "response";
@import "confirm_box";
@import "inner-pages";
@import "homepage";
@import "account_request";
```

The file that I am trying to use is account_request.scss. It's contents are :

```
.label_account_request{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

However, I am not able to view the result of my email field. Here is a screenshot. What do I need to change in my code?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20qtm.png)

Comment: Probably another CSS overwrites your code (has higher priority). To verify that, use `font-weight: bold !important;` and check if the label is bold.

Comment: Hi, I used your approach, and after making your modification it works! Thanks! I got confused because I did not see any overwriting behavior from the other style sheets.

Comment: Definitely there is something because `!important` priorities the "attribute". I will post my comment as a reply so it will be visible to everyone.

Comment: You should note that using `!important` is the nuclear option and generally not a good idea. https://j11y.io/css/dont-use-important/

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using !important then?

Comment: @KunalNarang of course there is :) You have to check what CSS rule is more important than yours. Here is a guide how to check which CSS rule is used: https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/how-determine-which-css-styling-element

Answer (score 1):

Probably another CSS overwrites your code (has higher priority).

To verify that, use `font-weight: bold !important;` and check if the label is bold.

Answer (score 0):

Write your label like:

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
```

The write your css like:

```
label[for="name"]{
/*write your styles here*/
}
```